# Como dar formato a un texto para enviarlo por mail?

Tags: c#, email

Muy buenas tardes estoy queriendo enviar por mail unos datos que obtengo de una consulta en la base de datos y lo he estado haciendo con el código que dejo abajo pero lo que necesito es enviar como un formato de tabla pero no se como armarlo en C#.

```
textoCamIng += string.Format("Cliente: {0} {1} Segmento: {2} ", objCl.NroIdent, objCl.Nombre, rowC[6].ToString());
string res = email.Send(row[0].ToString(), new List<string> { correoSegAnt }, new List<string> { seg }, "Notificaciones CRM: Ingresosss", textoCamIng );
```

Answer (score 0):

Si la variable `mail` es el `MailMessage` entonces debes definir la propiedad

[MailMessage.IsBodyHtml Property](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.mailmessage.isbodyhtml?view=netframework-4.8)

en `true`

Para poder usar algo como esto

```
string template = @"<html>
                        <body>
                            <p><b>Cliente:</b> {0} {1} </p>
                            <p><b>Segmento:</b> {2}</p> 
                        </body>
                    </html>"

string textoCamIng = string.Format(template, objCl.NroIdent, objCl.Nombre, rowC[6].ToString());

email.IsBodyHtml = true;
string res = email.Send(row[0].ToString(), 
                        new List<string> { correoSegAnt }, 
                        new List<string> { seg }, 
                        "Notificaciones CRM: Ingresosss", 
                        textoCamIng );
```